# How to show the product attribute in the product listing page Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute, magento-catalog

How to show the product attribute in the Product listing page i had used the helper in Magento_Catalog **(Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml)** but it gives the value of the product attribute not label the attribute type is Dropdown.

```
$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getManufacturer(), 'manufacturer');
```

I got the out as **5755**

I want to get the value using above method how can we do this.

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: check this image https://nimb.ws/1k6HdE this is yes or not ???

Comment: @Mohit Patel all the options are Yes only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1:

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Method 2:

```
$manufacturer = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer');
echo $manufacturer->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product);
```

Comment: if it is in XML how can i get this